# Unity Animation trouble

Tags: unity, unityscript

I am trying to make an animtion for my Sword so that when I click with my left mouse button, the sword gets swung. I watched a tutorial video and tried to follow all the steps but whats happening is that the Sword animtion gets played automatically in a loop

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Attack");
        }
    }
}
```

I know this isn't much to work with but maybe someone knows what I could have done wrong in the previous steps

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to your animation's asset and set **Loop Time** value to *false*. Depending on the type of animation asset, it might be called **Wrap Mode**, set it to *Once* in this case.

Comment: hey my teacher told me the same thing so I think it'll work, thanks

Comment: ok It did something, it stopped the animation from getting played all the time, but now when I press "Fire", the game pauses

Comment: That's really weird. I don't think it's caused by this script.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now.
The game pausing everytime I swung the sword, was because in the console, error pause was on, so everytime an error occurs, the game pauses.

And one of the errors was telling me something about it having to be marked as legacy and how to change that is by setting the inspector of the animation to "debug" as shown in the picture

[image]